# COUNT values in column and produce table of results mysql

Tags: php, mysql

To preface this question - I know I'm missing something really obvious here but it is Friday afternoon!

I'm trying to COUNT to number of times certain values appear within the same column and produce a table of the results.

Here's my code so far:

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(order_status) as printed
FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'Printed Order'

UNION

SELECT COUNT(order_status) as charged
FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'Charged Order'

UNION

SELECT COUNT(order_status) as exchanged
FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'Exchanged Order'

UNION

SELECT COUNT(order_status) as refunded
FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'Refunded Order'

UNION

SELECT COUNT(order_status) as cancelled
FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'Cancelled Order'
GROUP BY order_status
```

**Result of the above query**

```
printed
-------
224
19190
593
2618
2899
```

The code is producing the correct figures, however, I would prefer the result to look as follows:

**Desired result**

```
printed - 224
charged - 19190
exchanged - 593
refunded - 2618
cancelled -2899
```

This way I can easily reference them via associative array call i.e. `$order_status['printed']`

Any help would be great.

Comment: So, actually you want your SQL results provided as an associative array?

Comment: @fast - I suppose I do

Comment: Add the order_status to the select.  e.g. select order_status, count(order_status) ...

Comment: @aphextwix so you do not? strange..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a column specifying the type.  The easiest way is to use `group by`:

```
select order_status, count(*)
from orders o
group by order_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO, set the fetch mode to create associative arrays by default by:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
SELECT order_status, COUNT(order_status) as printed
FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'Printed Order'
GROUP BY order_status
```